# Looping numbers in python; 123456789

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

this ends up looking like 123456789 repeated. I need to adjust it to make a loop that prints

```
000000000
111111111
etc.
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing `i` in your loop and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, that was it. How does that work? I'm trying to read code but to the best of my ability I can't visualize the code reading "for j in range(10)" being of any use.

Comment: it simply does the same thing ten times, as you wished.

Answer (score 1):

You should be printing `i` in the inner loop, not `j`:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...    for j in range(10):
...         print(i, end=' ')
...    print()
...
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
>>>
```

`i` refers to what number needs to be written ten times.  `j` is just there to make the syntax valid for the second loop.  In fact, I would recommend renaming `j` to `_`:

```
for i in range(10):
   for _ in range(10):
        print(i, end=' ')
   print()
```

By convention, this means that you do not plan to use it inside the loop.

Comment: Interesting convention. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

as you going for loop 10 by 10 you can eliminate one for loop if your desired output is:

```
>>> for x in range(10):
...     print(str(x)*10)
...  
0000000000
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
5555555555
6666666666
7777777777
8888888888
9999999999
```